# Conditionally convergent sequences and implications

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If I have $\sum b_n$ is conditionally convergent, how can I show that $\sum b_{4n}$ doesn't in general converge?

Assume $(b_n)$ is an arbitrary sequence of the Reals

All I need is a counter example right?

Comment: 0, 1, 0, -1/2, 0, 1/3, 0, -1/4, 0, 1/5,...

Comment: ^helpful comment of the year

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, one has to find a counter-example in other to show that $S':=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n}$ may not converge.

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|$ is convergent, then so is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{2n} |$ and $S'$ converges. So, if $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a counter-example, then necessarily $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|a_{n} |$ does not converge.
But $S:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ has to be convergent; therefore, the convergence is due to a compensation.

One can think to a series such that the sign of the $n$th term is the opposite of that of the $(n+1)$th. This is called alternating series. So write $a_n :=(-1)^nb_n$, where $b_n\geqslant 0$. We want the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nb_n$ but not that for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{2n}b_{2n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{2n}$. We can finally choose $b_n :=1/n$.

Comment: cheers davide, understood

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a counterexample will do, e.g.
$$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \ldots $$